# block functions from JS objects in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I am having a bit of an issue that I have never seen before. Usually when I build JS "classes" I will just do the simple object style ...

```
var page = {
    add: function(k, v) {
        this[k] = v;
    }
}
```

I recently tried doing it with the var page = function() { blah blah } page.prototype = { style but now when I am trying to send off stuff through ajax everything breaks. I put in console logs to try to see what is happening and it seems that in the ajax call, the objects are being turned into window scope, and then the functions are trying to be parameterized. Horrible explanation, I apologize, here is the code, maybe it will make more sense...

```
var bioLocation = function(obj) {
    this.ID = 0,
    this.name = '',
    this.address = '';
    if(typeof obj != 'undefined') {
        return this.init(obj);
    }
}
bioLocation.prototype = {
    init: function(obj) {
        for(var index in obj) {
            this[index] = obj[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously a stripped down version of my real object, but a perfect representation. So then later on in the code I have a button even that will send data off over ajax to save some stuff like so.

```
$('.save').click(function() {
    var postData = {};
    var saveTest = new bioLocation({ID: $('.whatever').val()});
    postData.locations = saveTest;
    var reply;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(msg) {
            reply = msg;
        }
    });
});
```

Again, obviously a very simplified version of my code, but pretty much right on target. 
The problem is I am getting very strange errors...
"cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" the line will point directly to the second line of the init function in the bioLocations prototype.

I have done tons of console logs throughout the code, when I put them in the init method it will log twice, once when I create the object in the click function, and once in the ajax call. Here is the code with the console logs in it...

```
var bioLocation = function(obj) {
    this.ID = 0,
    this.name = '',
    this.address = '';
    if(typeof obj != 'undefined') {
        return this.init(obj);
    }
}
bioLocation.prototype = {
    init: function(obj) {
        console.log(this);
        for(var index in obj) {
            this[index] = obj[index];
        }
    }
}
```

So I will get 2 console logs when I click the submit button, the first shows...

bioLocation {ID: 5, name: '', address: ''}

then the second time it logs (still within the same click event) it will log...

Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object...}

and then I will get that error "Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined"

I can't figure out why it is logging it twice, and more so, why is the second log a Window object. It seems like the ajax call is trying to serialize the functions and getting errors, but I have never seen a prototype being serialized when the object is passed into ajax as a param. I can confirm that it is in fact trying to param the functions because with more logging and hair pulling I was actually able to see the ajax call in the network tab and it did in fact have the init: undefined as one of the params being passed to the ajax page.

So I guess my questions are, how do you stop jquery's ajax function from parameterizing the prototype piece of an object when using it as a param? And, why on earth is it actually adding the prototype into the the call?

Please, you gotta help me, I am loosing my mind here. I have never seen anything like this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `console.log(this, arguments)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor needs to return the new object, not the return value of the `init` function. Omit the `return` and it will return `this` by default. You also had commas where you should have had semi-colons. By convention, classes are capitalized.

```
var BioLocation = function (o) {
    this.ID = 0;
    this.name = '';
    this.address = '';
    if (typeof o !== 'undefined') {
       this.init(o);
    }
}
BioLocation.prototype = {
    init: function (o) {
        for (var i in o) {
            this[i] = o[i];
        }
    }
};
var saveTest = new BioLocation({ ID: 5 });
console.log(saveTest);
```